# C# remove first wraping div

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to remove the first  that appears in my reporting string.

```
Actual result:
<div><div><p>This is a test</p><ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul></div></div>

Expected result
<div><p>This is a test</p><ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul></div>
```

I've been trying to convert the whole string into an array so I can just remove the first and last element of it, but I'm having a hard time splitting it since there are no commas or spaces.

How can I procede? the HTML to be eliminated will always be that extra div

Comment: If it's always that, why not simply remove the first 5 and last 6 characters?

Comment: Are there any cases where you have CSS classes or anything in the div tag?  If it is always just opening and closing @NicoSchertler 's solution should be the easiest.

Comment: @NicoSchertler That's possible, but I wanted to see if there was a cleaner solution

Comment: Clean in what sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will take into account the case scenario where you have an attribute in the first div (I.E. `<div class='bla'> <div> text </div> </div>`).
For completeness and to avoid unhandled exception you should check for edge cases (such as empty strings, malformed html...)

```
    public string InnerDiv(string html)
    {
        var start_idx = html.IndexOf(">", html.IndexOf("<div", StringComparison.InvariantCulture), StringComparison.InvariantCulture) + 1;
        var last_idx = html.LastIndexOf("</div>", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        return html.Substring(start_idx, last_idx - start_idx);
    }
```